# MongoDB aggregation $match on third collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 3 collections: User, Link and LinkView.

```
User:
{
    "_id": "ID",
    "username": "nick"
}

Link:
{
    "_id": "ID",
    "url": "http://google.com/",
    "user": {
        "$ref": "User",
        "$id": "ID",
        "$db": "database_name"
    }
}

LinkView:
{
    "_id": "ID",
    "created": "date",
    "link": {
        "$ref": "Link",
        "$id": "ID",
        "$db": "database_name"
    }
}
```

Now I want to get LinkViews created by specific user, but when I try this $match it's return me empty data:

```
{
    $match: {
        "link.user.id" : "ID"
    }
}
```

How can I select LinkViews by specific user?

Sample data:

```
User:
{
    "_id" : "584e7fee1ccd5604a52ec901",
    "username" : "nick",
}

Link:
{
    "_id" : "584e814e1ccd5604ac025313",
    "url": "http://google.com/",
    "user": {
        "$ref": "User",
        "$id": "584e7fee1ccd5604a52ec901",
        "$db": "test"
    }
}

LinkView:
{
    "_id": "584e82191ccd560f0b690791",
    "created": "2016-12-12T09:54:10.000Z",
    "link": {
        "$ref": "Link",
        "$id": "584e814e1ccd5604ac025313",
        "$db": "test"
    }
},
{
    "_id": "584e82191ccd560f0b690795",
    "created": "2016-12-12T10:54:10.000Z",
    "link": {
        "$ref": "Link",
        "$id": "584e814e1ccd5604ac025313",
        "$db": "test"
    }
},
{
    "_id": "584e82301ccd560f0b690796",
    "created": "2016-12-12T11:54:10.000Z",
    "link": {
        "$ref": "Link",
        "$id": "584e814e1ccd5604ac025313",
        "$db": "test"
    }
}
```

Aggregation pipeline example:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [$project] => Array
            (
                [hour] => Array
                    (
                        [$hour] => $created
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [$match] => Array
            (
                [link.user._id] => 584e7fee1ccd5604a52ec901
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [$group] => Array
            (
                [_id] => $hour
                [value] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => 1
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: can you share full query that you tried and sample data for LinkView?

Comment: Added to text, hope is ok.

Answer (score 0):

To get the link views created by a user, you need a couple of **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** pipelines as follows:

```
db.user.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": "ID" } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "link",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "user",
            "as": "userlink"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$userlink" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "linkview",
            "localField": "userlink",
            "foreignField": "link",
            "as": "linkview"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Did you check the names of your collections to be correct, i.e. in the above they are all in lowercase `"from": "linkview",...` and `"from": "link",` but your question they are capitalised?

Comment: When I try these:
db.User.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"_id": ObjectId("584e7fee1ccd5604a52ec901")}},
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "Link",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "User",
            "as": "userlink"
        }
    }
]);

It works, but userlink is empty and when I add { "$unwind":"$userlink" } it return me empty result :/

Comment: There can be problem that field User in Link collection is DBRef probably? I have designed DB in PHP Doctrine ODM.